# Multiple Time Frames

Tags: pine-script

You have a typical candlestick chart in the main pane using a 1-day (base) time frame and in the pane below it, you have the 14-day EMA but the EMA is plotted using a 15 minute time.

The problem I have is that the EMA is not being displayed the way I want it to if the base time frame is set to Day. It shows what looks like a condensed version of the 15-minute chart, instead of displaying it as if the base time frame was also set to 15 minutes.

In other words, the second pane's display should not change when you switch between a Day and a 15-minute chart on the main pane above.

Is there a way of forcing the second pane to display the 15-minute chart regardless of what the main pane is set to?

```
//@version=4
study("EMA", precision=2, overlay=true, resolution="15")

EMA       = ema(close,13)
EMA_HIGH  = highest(EMA, 21)
EMA_LOW   = lowest(EMA, 21)
EMA_STO   = (EMA - EMA_LOW) / (EMA_HIGH - EMA_LOW) * 100
EMA_STO_R = rising(EMA_STO,4)
EMA_STO_F = not rising(EMA_STO,4)

plotColour = EMA_STO == 100 ? color.lime :
       (EMA_STO >= 75 and EMA_STO_R == true) ? color.lime :
       (EMA_STO <= 65 and EMA_STO_R == true) ? color.green :
       (EMA_STO >= 75 and EMA_STO_F == true) ? color.yellow :
       (EMA_STO <= 65 and EMA_STO_F == true) ? color.red : 
       color.white

plot(EMA_STO,    style=plot.style_columns, color=plotColour, transp=60)

H1 = hline(75, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.green)
H2 = hline(65, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.red)
fill(H1,H2, color=color.white, transp=90)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because there's only 1 time axis. That time axis needs to be kept consistent over all panes. That's why your plot is condensed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. I'm working around the problem by now using a 15-minute chart and adjusting all my or "D" calculations with this:

```
OPEN_LTF   = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
HIGH_LTF   = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
LOW_LTF    = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)
CLOSE_LTF  = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)
VOLUME_LTF = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", volume)
Length_LTF = timeframe.isdaily ? 1 : 32
```

This gives me blocks of 32 bars showing the day value, but also all the 15-minute data as needed, using the updated length as needed.